# why tag audio in html5 not working and not playing in ios ? any solution

Tags: html, audio, html5-video, html5-audio, autoplay

I write code it works in android and windows but the audio not working on ios, I try with video but not working too

this my code html

```
<video width="0px" height="0px" autoplay playsinline>
    <source src="audio.mov" type="video/mp4">
  </source>
</video>
```

i hope can play audio in ios

Comment: Is the device on silent?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.